# How to import a VBPROJ into visual studio express 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I have a VBPROJ (plus all source) which as created in Visual Studio 2005. How do I import it into visual studio express 2008 ?

Please note that this is my first time using either VB or visual studio express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File->Open->Project/Solution

Then just browse to the file.

This assumes you're using Visual Basic 2008 Express. Clearly the C# edition won't open that project.

Comment: What's the exact error message. I know VS2008 Professional can upgrade from VS2005 projects.